# JPA update record is failing due to @OneToMany

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have a very small doubt regarding @OneToMany mapping.

I have a model student and another model attendance.

A student can have multiple attendance. but student model should only be able to retrieve the attendance info.

But when I am trying to change some student info I am getting below error as it is trying to update attendance record.

here is my mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student_detail")
@Getter @Setter
public class StudentDetailsModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name="reg_no",updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String regNo;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name = "reg_no")
    private List<AttendanceModel> attendances;
}
```

and the exception I a getting.

```
    update
        student_detail 
    set
        address=?,
        alt_contact_number=?,
        blood_group=?,
        contact_number=?,
        dob=?,
        father_name=?,
        first_name=?,
        gender=?,
        last_name=?,
        middle_name=?,
        mother_name=?,
        photo_url=?,
        school_id=? 
    where
        reg_no=?
Hibernate: 
    update
        attendance 
    set
        reg_no=null 
    where
        reg_no=?
2019-01-13 12:12:52.922  WARN 10708 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502
2019-01-13 12:12:52.923 ERROR 10708 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: null value in column "reg_no" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, 1, 2019-01-05, t, 2).
2019-01-13 12:12:52.926  INFO 10708 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [reg_no]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

my attenance model is as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name="attendance")
@Getter @Setter
public class AttendanceModel {

    //@EmbeddedId
    //private AttendanceId attendanceId;

    @Id
    @Column(name="attendance_id")
    private long id;


    @Column(name="reg_no")
    private String regNo;

    @Column(name="subject_id")
    private long subjectId;

    @Column(name="class_date")
    private Date classDate;


    @Column(name="present")
    private boolean present;
}
```

Comment: It should try to update attendance record. You have set the cascade property to ALL.

Comment: Can you post AttendanceModel? And did you try to add JointColumn(nullable =true,...) but It set null by default..

Comment: @NimaAJ  what should be my correct cascading type? I have tried with CascadeType.Remove same problem is there

Comment: @JonathanJohx , I have updated that in question

Comment: Okay, @soumyasambitKunda what database are you using?

Comment: Also can you  update @Column(name="reg_no", nullable = true)?

Comment: I am usingPOSTgressql DB

Comment: if I will update reg_no nullable to true , then it will be updated to null right?

Comment: Remove this line from your code ` @JoinColumn(name = "reg_no")` and this will fix your issue. Or follow @squalltrt answer below

Comment: @AjitSoman : I think this is also trying to set the reg_no to null. if in some case the reg_no = attendance_id then this will fail. In this particular case both will not be same. if I will follow squalltrt's solution

Answer (score 1):

Could you show me Student Model.If i look your code post : You using Unidirectional relationship.

I think it must :

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY , cascade = CascedeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="attendance_id")
private List<AttendanceModel> attendances = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: I have edited the question and added the student model.

Comment: I think this is also trying to set the reg_no to null. if in some case the reg_no = attendance_id then this will fail. In this particular case both will not be same.

Comment: Because you using same field name JoinColumn and primary key reg_no. You set primary key updatable = false, nullable = false . When you use update, hibernate find reg_no and throw exception because you has set it null in primary key. If you want update, change name is join JoinColumn or remove updatable = false, nullable = false in StudentDetailsModel.